# Limit decimals from import calculated value in power BI

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am using Power apps to input technical information. That information is saved in a SharePoint Site. A field is automatically calculated in SharePoint with a fixed number of decimals. The value is then pushed back in PowerBI as text to display but with all decimals.

I've tried to limit the number of decimals in the text field using the following value:

```
Text(Value(Parent.Default),"##.##")
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

The error message translates to:

> Unexpected characters. The formula contains 'error' while 'Parenclose' is expected. Characters are used in the formula in an unexpected way.

How can I limit the number of decimals in the text?